# Picture gets distorted when updating linked picture if the external picture size has changed. (Word 2013)

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2013

When I update a picture using "Edit Links To Files", and the size of the source picture has changed, Word 2013 distorts the aspect ratio so that the updated picture looks squished (i.e., it still uses the dimensions of the old picture, not the new picture).

This worked correctly in older versions of Word (2000, 2003), but now seems to be functioning incorrectly in Word 2013.

This happens with different types of image files as well (I've mostly been using linked EPS files).

Does anyone have a workaround for this?